# How to redirect the custom button on product page

Tags: magento2

Newbie here. How can I redirect the customize button on its product page?

[image]

I've created the button inside the list.phtml

`<button type="submit" id="subs" style="margin-bottom:5px;" onclick="window.location.href='{The bag product URL}';">Subscribe</button>`

Comment: Submit is used to send form. If you have a form the submit will send you to the action link of your form. If you don't have, any, then you need to do this directly with some js.

Comment: Okay, but how can I get the product url?

Comment: Checkout this file path - vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml , in the line no 71 for magento latest version 2.4.5 ,they have used the product object to get the product URL like this = $_product->getProductUrl() , the $_product object comes from the $_productCollection , please do let me know if any more help is needed.

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. Also could you help me on this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359940/how-to-extend-the-appearance-of-an-extension-on-the-product-list-page @BharathKumarJ

Comment: Very Happy that it works , can you please do give me a like , this helps me motivate more to post answers , and sure will check out this post.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do it like this.

```
<?php $productUrl = $_product->getProductUrl();?>
<a href="<?= $productUrl ?>">Subscribe</a>
```