# How to extend the appearance of an extension on the product list page

Tags: magento2

Newbie question. How do I extend the appearance of an extension?

I would like this extension/view:

[image]

**to add in here:**

[image]

Here are my default Catalog_category_view.xml

```
        <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
            
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

and here's the also the default extension's xml:

```
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
        <block class="Amasty\RecurringPayments\Block\Product\View\RecurringPayments"
               name="product.info.recurring.payments"
               before="product.info.addtocart"
               template="Amasty_RecurringPayments::product/view/subscriptions.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

the list.phtml is where I'd like to extend the extension's appearance/view

here's what I've added but couldn't work (below the line with the exclamation points!):

```
        <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
                <!!!!!!!!what I've added!!!!!!!!!!!!!!>
                <block class="Amasty\RecurringPayments\Block\Product\View\RecurringPayments"
                name="product.info.recurring.payments"
                before="product.info.addtocart"
                template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml"/>
            </block>
            
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

and here's my list.phtml code and the inserted code that I get from the extension's phtml file:

[enter link description here](https://codeshare.io/nzmZEv)

Answer (score 0):

The change you are asking is from a block in the product view page , for more info i need you get the block name from the layout path and you can use that block name in the layout file = catalog_category_view.xml file in your custom module or theme and place the block in that to show this content.

For example , please see the below code i have used to print a "Block you want" content in the category view page using the layout handle file = catalog_category_view.xml file and have over-ride a block called "category.product.addto.wishlist" and in that block's template have appended my content also ,i know there are many approaches but by far this is the best i have arrived to and it requires minimum level of coding and over-riding the file also, below is the code

If this code snippet helps you please do give me a like , this helps me motivate to post more answers , have a nice day.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="category.product.addto.wishlist"
                   template="OX_PrintSampleContent::wishlist.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Below is the phtml file

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var Magento\Wishlist\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Wishlist $block */
?>
<h1>Block you want here</h1>
<?php if ($block->getWishlistHelper()->isAllow()) : ?>
    <a href="#"
       class="action towishlist"
       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Wish List')) ?>"
       aria-label="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Wish List')) ?>"
       data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAddToWishlistParams($block->getProduct()) ?>'
       data-action="add-to-wishlist"
       role="button">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')) ?></span>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Below is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Hi @harathKumarJ Thanks for this. I know that you answered my question, but the connection between my module catalog and the extension's xml, php, and phtml files is giving me trouble. Is there a way I can contact you? I looked at your LinkedIn page; perhaps we can talk there. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Yes, please ask your queries here, I'll help out as much as possible.Thank you

Comment: Hi @bharath Kumar J- Please check my updated post, about this. Thank you.